# Read data from two CSC file with using Join to store a table by using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS. (I am a learning stage but had some task). I have two CSV file. Both files have 3 columns. One file has `FYON`, `Family`, `Number`.

[image]

Another file has `Family`, `Number`, `Description`.

[image]

The both Family and Number columns are relational columns for both files.

I want to read the values from those files and need to store the data in SQL server table as below columns

```
+----+------+--------+--------+-------------+
| ID | Fyon | Family | Number | Description |
+----+------+--------+--------+-------------+
|  1 |   50 | AP     |     01 | SV32        |
+----+------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Also I want to store the error in error table if the data is null or duplicate

I don't know how can I achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need can use a lookup transformation or a merge join to join the data together, then just write that to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple merge transformation in SSIS would do this for you. You need to read data from both files, sort them and then MERGE them (just number field should be sufficient) and then push all the required columns fom both the sources to the SQL table (OleDB Destination/SQL Server Destination).
Look at the second example here: http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/ssis-merge-and-mergejoin-example.php

Comment: Is it possible to join for two columns?? I have use Merge join. But I am unable to join use two column.

Comment: Yes, you can use a derived column to concatenate both the columns and then use that as the merging column. But just check if you really need to do that or just "Number" field is sufficient. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did that help??

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by myself with help of @deepak  answer. finally the flow  is

[image]